# Prove that $\phi(n)\geq\sqrt{n}$ for $n \neq 2$ and $n\neq 6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is a prime, this is certainly true since $\phi(n)=n-1$ if $n$ is a prime.
If $n$ is a composite number, then $n$ can be factorized as $\prod_{k=1}^{y}p_{k}^{a_k}$, where $p_i$ are primes, $i$ an integer. Also $\phi(p^i)=p^{i}-p^{i-1}$. It is also given that $\phi(n)$ is a multiplicative function.
Using these facts, prove that $\phi(n)\geq\sqrt{n}$ for $n \neq 2$ and $n\neq 6$.
And what is the special property in $2$ and $6$? Why are they the only numbers that don't satisfy this property?[**Note:**$\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function.]
[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) is the wikipedia article on it.

Comment: Hint:  prove it for prime powers, then extend by the multiplicative property.

Comment: Probably nothing too fancy, except the fact that the obvious idea of studying the prime powers has the caveat of not working for $2(2k+1)$, and that $\sqrt{2(2k+1)}\le \phi(2k+1)$ doesn't work for $k=1$.

Comment: I was content with "2 and 6 being too small".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah.....  so in general $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1) > p^{\frac k2}$.  In general.  After all if $k>1$ then $k-1 \ge \frac k2$ with equality holding only if $k=2$, in which case $p-1 >1$ in general, unless $p = 2$.

More specifically.  If $p; p\ge 2$ is a prime and $k> 0$ (no point in calculating $\phi(1) = 1$)  then $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1) \le p^{\frac k2}$ if and only if $\frac {p^{k-1}}{p^k} =p^{\frac k2 -1} \le \frac 1{p-1} \le 1$. And as $p>1$ that requires $\frac k2 -1 \le  0$ so as $k \ge 1$ we can only have this true if $k = 1$.

So for $\phi(p^k) \le p^{\frac k2}$ we must have $k=1$ and so we must have $\phi p = (p-1)\le \sqrt {p}$.  But if $p \ge 3$ then $(p-1)^2 = p^2 - 2p +1=3p-2p + 1 = p+1 >p >\sqrt p$.  So $p^k =2$ and $\phi 2 = 1 < \sqrt 2$ is the only time $\phi(p^k) < \sqrt{p^k}$.

So that is one case where $\phi(n) \le \sqrt n$.  And that is the only case where $n$ is of the form $p^k$.  But what if cases with multiple prime divisors?

If $n=2^m\prod_{p_i\ne 2} p_i^{k_i}$ then to have $\phi(n) \le \sqrt n$ we must have $\phi(n) =2^{m-1} \prod p_i^{k_i-1}\prod (p_i-1)\le 2^{\frac m2}\prod p_i^{\frac {k_i}2}$.  But as every $p_i\ne 2$ we have $p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i -1) > p_i^{\frac {k_i}2}$ we must have $2^{m-1}<2^{\frac m2}$ which can only happen if $m=1$.

so we must have $n = 2\prod p_i^{k_i}$ and we must have $\phi n = \prod p_i^{k_i-1}\prod(p_i-1) \le  \sqrt 2\prod p_i^{\frac {k_i}2}$ or $\prod p_i^{\frac {k_i}2 -1}\prod (p_i-1) \le \sqrt 2 < 3$.  so $\prod (p_i-1) < 3$.

But as $p_i-1 > 1$ we must have *each* $p_i -1< 3$ and the only such $p_i$ where $p_i -1 < 3$ and $p_i \ne 2$ is $p_i =3$, we must have $n = 2\times 3^k$.

And then $\phi(n) = 2\times 3^{k-1} \le \sqrt 2 3^{\frac k2 -1}$ or $3^{\frac k2 -1} \le \frac 1{\sqrt 2}< 1=3^0$ so $\frac k2 - 1 < 0$ so $k=1$.

And $\phi(2\times3) = 2< \sqrt 6$ is the only $n$ with multiple prime divisors with the property.

Answer (score 1):

For $p^a$, $p$ prime, since $1\ge \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p}\ge\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^{a/2}}$, $$\phi(p^a)=p^a-p^{a-1}\ge p^{a/2}$$ except for $a=1$. In fact, for $p\ge3$, a stronger inequality holds, $1\ge \frac{1}{p}+\frac{2}{p^{a/2}}$, so $\phi(p^a)\ge2p^{a/2}$.

For $a=1$, $\phi(p)=p-1\ge\sqrt{2p}$ except for $p=2,3$. In these exceptional cases, $\phi(2)=1\not>\sqrt2$, but $\phi(3)=2\ge\sqrt{3}$, $\phi(3)\not>\sqrt2\sqrt3$.

Hence,
$$\phi(n)=\phi(2^a\prod_ip_i^{a_i})=\phi(2^a)\prod_i\phi(p_i^{a_i})\ge\sqrt{2^a}\prod_i p_i^{a_i/2}=\sqrt{n}$$ except when $a=1$, and $p_1=3$, $a_1=1$, or there are no other primes.

---

To clarify: The only case when the inequality does not hold is when $a=1$, so $\phi(2)\not>\sqrt{2}$. However, if (i) there is a prime $p\ge 5$, then $\phi(p^b)\ge \sqrt{2}\,p^{b/2}$ compensates; or (ii) if there are no primes $p\ge 5$ but there is a factor $3^b$, $b\ge2$, in which case $\phi(3^b)\ge\sqrt{2}\,3^{b/2}$, again compensating.